# Send touch (x,y) coordinates between 2 different screens android

Tags: android, android-touch-event

Assume I have a large screen device and a small screen device, now if I touched the large screen device at some random x,y like this:

```
//on touch event

float x = event.getX();
float y = event.getY();
```

And send these to the smaller screen device, how do I know on the small screen device where that x,y coordinate must be?

**In other words if it was at the top right corner on the larger screen device, it must be at the top right corner on the small screen device**

Answer (score 1):

Most important for this is you need to have widths of both screens, and calculate it proportionally.
Suppose largeWidth = 400, smallWidth = 300, and your x on Large screen is 200.
Then if you have to calculate width on small screen, then simple math would help here.

```
smallX = x * smallWidth/LargeWidth
smallX = 200 * 300/400
smallX = 150
```

Comment: can you please make the answer more clear, I dont understand what you mean?